# Stuck at boot screen after update: Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

Tags: boot, grub2, gnome

Yesterday, I did the automated software update for ubuntu gnome 14.04, and the machine has stopped booting since then.
The upgrade gives out a new kernel which is 3.13.0-53-generic
from the previous  3.13.0.24-generic

All I get is the infinite wait at the gnome boot screen.
I am using a Thinkpad E430, This is the first time I encountered such an error, If any furthur info (logs etc.) are required, I can provide the same.[image]

[image]

update:
does this help??

Comment: I tried booting both the previous and the new kernel, both are stuck at the bootscreen.

Comment: Does pressing any keys reveal any error messages, or jsut a flashing `_`?

Comment: nopes.. It just stays there

Comment: question  updated .

Answer (score 1):

The Issue is fixed, My gdm was broken.

I referred to this thread for help..

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2231856

I found out when I did

**sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm**

after which all I had to do was

**sudo apt-get install gdm**